# Multicondition sql statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table with users and countries either UK or US, now a user can appear multiple times with a different country. I need to select a list with unique users with their country either equal to UK, US or BOTH.

This is the approach Im trying but it doesn't appear to be working.

```
select user, 
    case 
        when COUNT(*) <= 1 and count(select where = "UK") = count(*) then "UK"
        when COUNT(*) <= 1 and count(select where = "US") = count(*) then "US" 
        when COUNT(*) <= 1 and count(select where = "US") != count(*) then "BOTH"
    END CASE
as country from users;
```

First time using logic like this in a query so sorry for sounding like a noob.

```
+------------------------------+-------------+
| user                         | country     |
+------------------------------+-------------+
| John                         | US          |
| Jack                         | US          |
| John                         | UK          |
| Joe                          | US          |
| John                         | UK          |
| Jacky                        | US          |
+------------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please provide the table structure and perhaps a few entries.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT 
    temp.user,
    if(temp.CountryList = "UK,US", "BOTH", temp.CountryList) as country
FROM
(
     SELECT 
         user,
         group_concat(DISTINCT country ORDER BY country) as CountryList
     FROM USERS
     GROUP BY user
) temp
```